# Document structure navigation in LibreOffice/OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, navigation

Is there "Document structure" toolbar in Libre Office or Open Office?

I would like to navigate documents inside Libre Office or Open Office by document structure (table of content) like I can do in "bookmarks sidebar" in SumatraPDF: 
[image]

or Navigation sidebar in new Microsoft Word:
[image]

Is there any plugin for this?

There is Navigation and Navigator in Libre Office and Open Office but they can't display document structure.

Comment: How about clicking that icon with the up and down arrows on Navigator?

Answer (score 1):

That's just press "Listbox ON/OFF" [image: Listbox ON/OFF] in Navigator. And then here it is under "Headings".

[image]

Thanks to random ♦.

Comment: Another way to do that - is to make a clickable table of contents for Your document.